# Biztalk out put Flat File has empty Records, how to avoid / remove

Tags: biztalk, flat-file, biztalk-mapper

I am converting XML file to Flat file. I am struggling for two things.

1. Want to achieve tag number without mapping file tag field from source to destination. Is there any way where I can populate it if in case any value in entire row. It shouldn't display tag number if record is empty.
2. After i map fields, if there is no value then blank records is visible as below

   ```
   101 JOB3434343 34343KKKK

   301 SSSSJooojs kkkkkkkk
   ```

In the above, between 101 and 301 there is 201 which doesn't have any output value. But still the blank record is visible in output file. Please advice if anyone can.

What i am doing is as below,
[image]

there in flattening value mapping i am passing tag numbers as 101,201 and 301. however i want to see best approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For #2, Jobs_201 is probably created because there is a JOB_DETAILS record in the source that is essentially empty.  You will have to link up some conditional functoids (do a Length > 0 on SLEVEL and STTYPE for instance) and link that to Jobs_201 to suppress the empty records.

Can you elaborate for #1 a bit.  If you want a counter, you can use a technique similar to this: http://blogdoc.biztalk247.com/article.aspx?page=ec141ab4-78a7-4012-9273-2a50669b41e2